# module lookup disabled by GOPROXY=off, but go env shows GOPROXY is set

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, go-modules, goproxy

When trying to lookup some modules, I am having an issue from VS Code where the error pictured below indicates that my GOPROXY is set to off, but when I run `go env`, I see that GOPROXY is actually set:`GOPROXY="https://repo1.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/go/golang-virtual,https://proxy.golang.org,direct"`

I have tried setting `GONOPROXY=''`, as [this comment suggests](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/39835#issuecomment-649827269), but after running `export GONOPROXY=` or `export GONOPROXY=""`, and checking go env in a new terminal tab, GONOPROXY is still set to: `GONOPROXY="*.mycompany.com"`

Running `go mod tidy` as VS Code suggests, results in the same error message.

Is it possible that my go env values are being set somewhere that I don't know about, maybe a different version of Go's env vars? Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated.

VS Code's error screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you restart vscode from the same environment where you exported the variables?

Comment: Thanks. Reloading the vs code window alone was enough to fix my issue.

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more on what you were trying to do? ("lookup some modules")
The error message is very confusing (the `GOPROXY=off` in the message was set by gopls internally to prevent unwanted network access or module update) and needs to improve.

Comment: I was trying to "go run" my program, which I have been able to do in the past, but VS Code was throwing this error when I opened the project. I agree that the error message is confusing and needs to improve. Thanks for explaining that this was set by gopls. For some reason, reloading the screen in VS Code fixed the issue.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Simply `Ctrl + Shift + P`  >  Developer: Reload window

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, but what is the reason we have to do this?

Comment: This worked for me. I have restarted my VScode multiple times to reflect changes but that did not work. The Reload window resolved the issue.

Answer (score 8):

The latest docs have updated the `GOPROXY` flag [proxy.golang.org](https://proxy.golang.org/), which states:

> To opt-out of this module mirror, you can turn it off by setting GOPROXY=direct

So to bypass the proxy and fetch directly from the URLs in go.mod:

```
export GOPROXY=direct

go clean --modcache
go get -u
go build
```